# Необходим совет по Service

Tags: java, android

У меня в приложении есть `Service`, который осуществляет запись звука. (Foreground)

Я хочу чтобы при закрытии приложения (удалении из оперативной памяти, а не сворачивании) и при открытии занова приложения, там было бы актуальное состояние View (play, stop, pause).

Взаимодействие с `Service` осуществляю с помощью `Intent + BroadcastReceiver`.

Как это можно реализовать?
Ну play можно узнать по отправке постоянных сообщений сервисов о изменение recordingTime.

А вот как с другими?
Сейчас такое взаимодействие:

- Кнопка отправляет `Intent` о действию `service`. `Service` отправляет
  сообщение о начале этого действия.
- Это сообщение я ловлю в `BroadcastReceiver` и выполняю функцию у `ViewModel` о смене статуса.
- `ViewModel` наблюдает за этим статусом, и если он изменился то
  обновляет UI.

Проблема только в том, что сообщение о pause, stop,
   resume сервис отправляет один раз. И если приложение в это время
   закрыто (собственно и `BroadcastReceiver` не инициализирован), то
   приложение не получит это сообщение

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо использовать explicit broadcast receiver, он будет отлавливать сообщения когда приложение не запущено. Для этого его необходимо зарегистрировать в манифесте. 
[Подробнее здесь:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46121548/5394219)

Comment: и как можно получить последнее сообщение в BroadcastReceiver при открытии приложении?

Comment: BroadcastReceiver может служить точкой входа в приложение, из него Вы можете запустить нужный Вам компонент (activity или service), положив в интент нужное сообщение. Либо сохранять его в БД и при запуске приложения, проверять есть ли сообщения

Comment: а как вам идея, что Сервис будет постоянно отправлять сообщения о своем состоянии, и когда мы открываем приложение, то broadcastreceiver в нем ловим сообщение и сразу меняет свое состояние?

Comment: Боюсь, что батарейка улетит за полчаса)

Comment: т.е мне нужно использовать 2 broadcastReceiver, или мой текущий нужно заменить на explicit?